# Stash: Test if nested list has value from outside nested loop

Tags: stash

Yo,

I can't seem to figure this one out. I have a nested list of related Playa entires. Depending on if the list has a value, I want to show some code above the nested list.

```
<div class="well">
    <h4>How To Guides</h4>
    <ul>
    {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="related_guides-{e_id}"}
        <li><a href="{link}">{title}</a></li>
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
    </ul>
</div>
```

I only want to show the 'well' div IF there is something to show.

Here is the nested list:

```
{exp:stash:set_list:nested name="related_guides-{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes" scope="site" save="no" replace="no" refresh="1440"}
        {filt_related_guides site="ht"}
            {stash:link}{title_permalink="guides/index"}{/stash:link}
            {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {/filt_related_guides}
        {gen_related_guides site="ht"}
            {stash:link}{title_permalink="guides/index"}{/stash:link}
            {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {/gen_related_guides}
        {pump_related_guides site="ht"}
            {stash:link}{title_permalink="guides/index"}{/stash:link}
            {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {/pump_related_guides}
        {tub_related_guides site="ht"}
            {stash:link}{title_permalink="guides/index"}{/stash:link}
            {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {/tub_related_guides}

        {if no_results}{exp:stash:set_value name="no_related" value="0"}{/if}
    {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
```

Anyone got a solution to this? Or point out what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Well, you created your own solution.

To prevent conflicts, change the value of `no_related` to something diferent of "0".

```
{if no_results}{exp:stash:set_value name="no_related" value="yes"}{/if}
```

Then, use a conditional, but put this code on an embed, to make it be parsed **after** your nested list:

```
{if "{exp:stash:get name='no_related'}" != "yes"}
    <div class="well">
        <h4>How To Guides</h4>
        <ul>
        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="related_guides-{embed:e_id}"}
            <li><a href="{link}">{title}</a></li>
        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
        </ul>
    </div>
{/if}
```

Or, you can just use the `not_empty` single variable and to no create the `no_related`:

```
{if {exp:stash:not_empty name="related_guides-{embed:e_id}"}}
    <div class="well">
        <h4>How To Guides</h4>
        <ul>
        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="related_guides-{embed:e_id}"}
            <li><a href="{link}">{title}</a></li>
        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
        </ul>
    </div>
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks Robson. I thought I was almost there. I will give them a go. I'd not seen the not_empty tag before. Very useful. Thanks again.